# Adding a scroll background change event

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ListView background scroll with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278623/listview-background-scroll-with-data)

I want to make my background to repeat itself as I scroll down a listview to make the list look like everything is moving at the same time. Can someone guide me to doing this?

Comment: No it's not a duplicate of that question. I want the image to simulate a scrolling even as my items scroll as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following:

> - add on scroll listener
> - count the position of the scroll
> - crop the image to the scroll postion
> - fill the portion of the background with drawable which is part of the image

Comment: That might be it. I will start researching on how to achieve this. Thank you.